# How do you change the URL that is pushed from Woocommerce to the facebook shop?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

Two months ago I launched a wordpress website(www). It didn't do so well so I decided to create a subdomain (develop) and create a new site on there.

After completing development I was instructed to copy the files from the sub(develop) over to the main(www)

This worked fine and everything was displaying as it should on the new www site, however.

I've recently installed the facebook-for-woocommerce-1.2.4 on my WordPress shop. When I push my products to facebook they get listed with my develop domain.

From my limited wordpress/woocommerce/facebook knowledge I found that the URL is called via get_home_url(). I've contacted facebook, my ISP and WooCommerce if they know how I can correct this but they couldn't give me the answer.

It's most likely in the database (they said) but I have less knowledge with mySql than PHP. I've clicked through the tables but found nothing.

All my permalinks are set up correctly, unless there is a hidden one I missed.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Check out this [facebook for woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Look in wp_options table, you will find your site url, home url there. Change that... that's all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked that table on all three databases I have but all of them display the correct www URL. I'm trying to add the products to facebook again (for the third time) to see if it hopefully corrects itself(doubtful).

Comment: have you created any FB app for this ?

Comment: I have, but only for social logins on my site.

Comment: My sentiment exactly. Installed the plugin, uploaded the shop to FB and boom. Wrong site. Waiting for feedback from WooCommerce. Will update once I have an answer. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Deleted it and installed a different plugin. All good now. Thanks for the help!